# Starting a UIViewController from background in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, voip

I am writing an iOS VoIP app that has background mode permission. In background, it will be listening for incoming connection, and once I have an incoming connection, it should start a `UIViewController` for the user to accept the call. **How and where to call and present a `UIViewController` from background?**

I know how to do this in Android, a Service would call an Activity via an Intent.

But in iOS , I am not sure how would the flow go. Also, **how do I go into background mode in iOS?** I know it has to do with the appDelegate method `applicationDidEnterBackground`: , But not sure what to do next.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know about your first question, but you go into the background when the user or the OS puts you there (home, lock, call, ...).

Comment: Okay, so when the app goes into background, the method applicationDidEnterBackground is called. Does this destroy the appDelegate? then, when I call a UIViewController from background, what method from appDelegate gets called?

Comment: Definitely does not destroy the app delegate object.  If the user brings you back to the foreground, the same object gets a notification of that too.  It's the concept "call a UIViewController from background" that has me a bit baffled.  You don't have access to the screen from the background, so I don't get what a view controller is going to do for you.

Comment: When you receive an incoming call, you will need to post a UILocalNotification to alert the user to the call and prompt them to launch your app. If they tap the notification or a launch the app from the icon you need to detect that you have a pending call and display the appropriate UI in applicationDidBecomeActive

Comment: Okay, I think I got a fairly good picture. So it is not possible to launch a screen directly from background like in Android, I have to have an intermediate local or remote notification that connects me to the app. I will give it a shot. Thanks!

Comment: @Paulw11 I am reading about UILocalNotification and it looks like these notifications cannot open the app. So my incoming call dialog will not be able to answer the calls. Can I still do it without using APN ? Also, what do you think apps like Viber use for such a task?

Comment: On iOS you can never force an app to open - only the user can open your app.  On ios8 you can provide actions buttons on the local notification such as "answer" and "reject" - if the user taps these then your app will be brought to the foreground and you will know which button they tapped.  If the user simply ignores the notification then your app will not be brought to the foreground.  You can also play an alert sound with the notification

Answer (score 1):

there are two methods in `appDelegate` that will be called when the app returns to active state. First one is `- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application` and the second one is `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application`

In the 2nd you have to restore your user interface.